# Plane-train interchange time in Copenhagen

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, copenhagen, cph

I'm planning to fly into Copenhagen (Kastrup airport) on an early morning flight, taking a train to a business meeting, and fly back in the evening. My schedule will be tight, so I'd like to know what transfer times I can expect between the train and the plane.

I'll assume my plane lands on time (otherwise I at least have an excuse). Approximately how long after the plane arrival time can I expect to be on the platform waiting for the next train (so cross the airport, get from my terminal (2 or 3 depending on the [airline](http://www.cph.dk/CPH/UK/MAIN/Before+Departure/Airlines.htm)) to the station, buy a ticket)? I'll be coming from the Schengen Area, so I won't be going through customs. I won't have any luggage to retrieve.

On the way back, I'll have already checked in online. The airport website has scarily high [recommended arrival time](http://www.cph.dk/CPH/UK/MAIN/Before+Departure/Recommended+arrival.htm), but since it's by company I assume that includes checkin time, not just going through security. How much time should I reasonably allow to get through security in the early evening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That depends on where you need to go for the meeting. If it's somewhere on the metro line, you can expect to be on the metro - with a paid ticket - within 30 min of touchdown, and in central Copenhagen within 20 min after that.

If it's not on the metro line, but still close to the city, you can add 10-15 minutes. As long as it's central Copenhagen, it's really efficient and the trains leave all the time. If it's outside central Copenhagen, the trains leave every 10/20 minute.

You can check the travel times at the Danish travel site [Rejseplanen](http://www.rejseplanen.dk/) (available in Danish, English, and German).

About check-in/security: It's usually really efficient. My personal experience is that one hour before at most hours is fine (and I usually still have time for my travel-smoothie), but to be safe, 1½ hours should be more than enough.

Comment: I'm taking the train — I'm actually going to Malmö. The train times aren't a problem, what I can't find information on is how much time to allow for walking through the airport, waiting for shuttles, queuing for a ticket, etc. Is there a difference in that respect between the metro and the train?

Comment: No, the train to Malmö is also really efficient. I would say 20-30 minutes from touchdown till you stand waiting for the Malmö train with a ticket :-) There is no shuttles and buying a ticket is very fast. Good signs and English speaking people everywhere too.